# Is there a way to set up Eclipse to debug from one app to another?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm building an app that is comprised of multiple APKs and I'm curious if it's possible to set up the debugger to follow along as one app invokes the next.

Is there such a feature? Or am I totally out of debugging luck on that front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DDMS perspective, there 'Devices' you follow each process emulator. So if your appA opening a second appB, this appears there as another process, just click on this to display your LogCat. And you can go alternating between them.